# Remove Left and right square brackets using sed/bash

Tags: linux, bash, sed, find

I have a file with this character `[Contributor]`. I.e the contributor and the bracess all together

I need to remove it using the code below:

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i 's@ [Contributor]@@g' {} +
```

Any Idea how I might achive this with find and sed combined. Or any other idea. the open and closed braces must be removed as well as the word contributor
Thanks

Comment: Escape `[` and `]` using `sed -i 's@\[Contributor\]@@g {}'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i understood you correctly this command should help:

```
sed -i 's/\[Contributor\]//g'
```